# a general table for different users, What if some has an access to add other

Tags: schema, relational-database

i have a reseller, a customer, a distributor and an admin.
made a single generic table **user**  ,**user-role** and a **role** table.
an admin can add and view all . a reseller can add a customer and a distributor can add a reseller.
please tell me if i have to make other tables like admin, customer, reseller, distributor. or a user table with roles can work

note: all actors have access to some specific other tables e.g. reseller can buy packages, customer can order a website

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach and

1. Have a separate table for permissions.
2. Give access to methods in application logic based on role.

I'd recommend method 1.

If you don't need to store additional information specific to each user based on their role I would favour the generic approach. But that is entirely dependent on your scenario

(ps- This is more of an opinion rather than an answer)